# Product of two circles and holomorphic functions

Tags: several-complex-variables

Assume that $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic functions in the unit disk having boundary values on the unit circle $T$ almost everywhere. Assume further that $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(e^{it})+g(e^{is})|dsdt<\infty.$$ Whether we can conclude that $\int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{it})|dt<\infty $ and $\int_0^{2\pi} |g(e^{is})|ds<\infty $?

Comment: It seems that this is an trivial question so it need to be closed.

Comment: For a.e. $s$, we have $\int |f(e^{it})+g(e^{is})|\, dt<\infty$ (and $g(e^{is})$ exists), so also $\int |f|<\infty$.

Comment: You can delete your question if it is no longer relevant.